# Checking internet connection with PNReachability class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, reachability, pubnub

I'm using Tony Million's [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) for displaying a `UIAlertView` if the device is not connected to the internet. It works almost correctly, but not perfect on iOS8. Fortunately I'm using the PubNub SDK and I discovered `PNReachability` class during my test session in the console that has a `checkServiceAvailable:` instance method which could do the same job as I think. Possibly somebody could confirm me that I'm right? Or is there any trick to check the internet connection with the PubNub SDK? As I discovered `PNReachability` works also after I call `[PubNub disconnect]` or before `[PubNub connect]` so it would be amazing for displaying "No Internet Connection" alerts across a project..

I would really appreciate any tips or guidance, using PubNub for this would make my life much easier, it's a really cool stuff you can trust in.

Answer (score 1):

Imported inside your project, you can check connectivity like this:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```

Using a specific `URL` for your request you can check if there is a connection to exactly this `URL`

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:gameApiHost];
```